# What PHP skills are required for magento?

Tags: magento2, php

I have a e-shop built with Opencart, so I know some things in PHP and MVC. But since Opencart is getting outdated with no recent updates, I want to switch to Magento 2.

What things do I need to learn in PHP to make a smooth transition?

Answer (score 2):

AKAIK open cart is also **e-commerce** platform.

**Between Magento2 and Open cart there are lot of common functionalities as well as both are e-commerce platform.**

Coming back  to your question - What things do I need to learn in PHP to make a smooth transition?

- So As per my opininon to learn Magento 2 (Special on code level) -
  you must have very good knowledge of OOPS(Object Oriented Programming
  Structure) concepts in PHP.
- Second thing which is important is - MVC - Magento 2 is totally based
  on MVC(Model View Controller) so you really needed strong knowledge
  of MVC part.
- Third but useful for frontend side - You have to at least good
  knowledge of basic javascript and jQuery , Magento 2 is using
  requireJs Concepts as well but that you will learn later on .

**So on a summarized manner you must have knowledge of - OOPS , MVC , CORE PHP**

Comment: Magento 2 mostly uses the MVVM model not MVC

Comment: @gabehou - Magento 2 mostly uses MVC for PHP part.. MVVM is used on frontend side for JS part - example : knockout js concept which uses MVVM. but on Php side it uses MVC.